# Window batch script that can execute a bat file, EXCLUDING ".svn" folder

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to search all of folder which contain compact.bat file exclusive .svn folder by window batch. If find the file compact.bat and execute it, after then to find next.

I've been search a lot reference but I don't know how to skip .svn folder name.
Can some expert help on this? thanks.

Comment: It would help if you posted code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%p in ('DIR compact.bat /l/b/a-d/s') do (
    set curPath=%%p
    set curPath=!curPath:.svn=!
    if !curPath!==%%p call %%p
)
```

Comment: thanks! it works. But if the directory name contain space and it shows errors.(directory name can't be "abc def")

Comment: Try this: `if !curPath!==%%p call "%%p"`